# sp_send_dbmail truncate rows at 256 characters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sp-send-dbmail

I would like to send a query results in the body of an HTML message via e-mail using `sp_send_dbmail`.

The (only) column `[HTML_body]` `(nvarchar(max))` of the table `##HTML_BODY` contains one row of style, one row for the table heads and one row for every rows of the table. The table contains 10 rows and every rows is 500-650 characters long.

I use the following:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
            @profile_name = 'ProfileMail'
            ,@recipients = 'me@mycompanydomain.domain'
            ,@subject = 'MySubject'
            ,@body = 'These are the values'
            ,@body_format = 'HTML'
            ,@query_result_width = 2000
            ,@query = ' SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT [HTML_body] FROM ##HTML_BODY SET NOCOUNT OFF'
            ,@file_attachments='\\ThePath\Graph.jpg'
            ,@attach_query_result_as_file = 0
            ,@query_result_separator = '|'
            ,@exclude_query_output = 1
            ,@query_result_no_padding = 1
            ,@query_result_header = 0
            ,@append_query_error=1
```

The code works but every row is truncated after 256 characters...can anyone have some idea of what could be the problem?
I have explicit that the `@query_result_width` should be 2000!

I am using SQL Server 9.0.4035 (2005), but didn't find any information about the compatibility with `@query_result_width`.

**Update**

I am having the same issue with SQL Server 12.0.2000 (2014)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `@query_no_truncate = 1` because of `nvarchar(max)`

My bold from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql)

> [ @query_no_truncate= ] query_no_truncate
>   Specifies whether to execute the query with the option that avoids truncation of large variable length data types (varchar(max), **nvarchar(max)**, varbinary(max), xml, text, ntext, image, and user-defined data types). When set, query results do not include column headers. The query_no_truncate value is of type bit. When the value is 0 or not specified, columns in the query truncate to **256** characters. When the value is 1, columns in the query are not truncated. This parameter defaults to 0.

Comment: If I add @query_no_truncate = 1 to the query, the mail is being sent (with the attached image) but there body doesn't contain any results. It seems like rows of more than 256 charachters are not being truncated but also are ignored.